# How can I let a div automatically set it own width?

Tags: css

How can I have a DIV's width behave like it does when `float:left` is set, but without setting a float? `width:auto` doesn't seem to do it (in chrome).

I am trying to get something like the following to work...

```
.center
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! It helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Solution with inline-block

You could try `display: inline-block` and see if that works in your situation. However, you won't be able to center it using `margin-left: auto` &  `margin-right: auto` because that technique requires a width value.

If possible, use `display: inline-block` and set `text-align: center` on it's container.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
     This will expand only as far as it needs to
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution using Flexbox + container div

The original answer above was written in 2011, before flexbox was implemented. You can achieve a similar effect

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div>
     This will expand only as far as it needs to
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution without container div

There is another way to do this without a parent element.

1. Set display to `inline-block` to make the div width fit to its content.
2. Use `position: relative` and `left: 50%` to position its left edge to 50% of its containing element.
3. Use `transform: translateX(-50%)` which will "shift" the element to the left by half its own width.

```
.center {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: hmm... that sets the width correctly, but the margins dont center the div now.

Comment: right, that's why I said that you'd have to add text-align: center to the container div.

Comment: I guess I can add another wrapper for the `text-align` but if at all possible I would rather not have to add another level of nesting. Do you know of any other ways to center a div of unknown width?

Comment: I do not. Doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks for the answer! I had been racking my brain on this for a few weeks, and had a really crappy fix in place; which didn't scale well.

Comment: solution without the container div for the win!

Answer (score 13):

I think this works nowadays:

```
.center
{
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's really useful.
Seems to be supported by all major browsers except IE: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content

Answer (score 6):

For those of you who are still coming across this issue, nowadays you can handle this with:

```
<div>
  <div style="display: table; margin: auto">
    This will expand only as far as it needs to
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a new fiddle based on the accepted answer: http://jsfiddle.net/j33qL8pa/1/

Answer (score 5):

`<div>`s are block elements. They take the full width of their containers. Period. Just like `<body>` or `<html>`

Your rule above is essentially doing this:
`div { width:100%; margin:0 auto; }` as 100% is its auto value.

`inline-block` would work, but it won't work exactly like a true `inline-block` element.

Basically...you can't do it without setting a width, positioning it.

If you go the inline-block route, give this a read...you may end up fighting some unexpected battles with your CSS expectations.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html (link found near the bottom of the following msdn page)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx