# Set dynamic height for highcharts chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a high charts height which has a variable number of rows.  I set it in a container with min-height of 300px, but when it has lots of entries they are all squashed.

How can I set the height dynamically?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712596/how-can-i-let-a-div-automatically-set-it-own-width
To make your container size automatic, use `display: inline-block`

Comment: That seems to work for the width, but not the height

Comment: Could you post a demo in JSFiddle showing the problem? How do you want to resolve the issue? How should height and width adjust?